# Python - How to justify string apart from last line

Tags: python, justify

I am doing a little challenge where I have to a single line of text to a specific width. e.g "Hello World I am doing something" with a width of 15 would go to:

```
Hello  World  I
am        doing
something
```

My current code is this:

```
def justify(text, width):
  return text.ljust(width)
```

This returns what I wanted apart from that the last line shouldn't be formatted at all

Any way I can justify all the text apart from the last line?

Thanks

Comment: Well in my example, the last line would be "somebody", however it gets confusing because you can't target the "last line" of a one line string, so I need a way to basically use .ljust() to format it into lines, then do some sort of algorithm to deal with the last line

Comment: Have you considered simply removing the last line before doing the justification, then adding the last line before returning from the function?

Comment: I don't think that will work because the text entered into the function is one line long

Comment: Related? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/95505/text-justification